# Detect ICMP requests on a Windows 10 System

Tags: windows-10, monitoring, icmp

I'm looking for a way to detect ICMP requests (e.g. ping) on a Windows 10 System. Unfortunately it does not work with netstat, since ICMP doesn't depend on a port hence all other light weight tools like TCPview won't work either.

Is there a native command to monitor for ICMP on a Windows 10 system? Alternatively I would go for a third party tool if there is no other solution, preferably something simpler / more light weight then Wireshark. Any hints/solutions are appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

> Unfortunately it does not work with netstat, since ICMP doesn't depend on a port

No; it's because the ICMP handler does not use a regular *socket*, but is built into the IP stack. But if you had a program that uses "raw sockets" to generate e.g. UDP or TCP packets (e.g. I think nmap qualifies) you wouldn't see them in netstat either.

Also, it wouldn't work anyway because ICMP is a datagram-based protocol, where a single "unconnected" socket can receive packets from all possible sources – even if it was UDP (which *does* show up in netstat), you'd typically see only a single "Foreign Address: `*:*`" socket even if the server was responding to 50 different clients.

> Is there a native command to monitor for ICMP on a Windows 10 system?

Windows 10 has `pktmon` since a 2018 release.

```
pktmon filter add -p ICMP
pktmon start --etw -m real-time
```

```
pktmon filter add -p ICMP
pktmon start -c
...
pktmon stop
pktmon etl2txt .\PktMon.etl
```

The traces are done at various OS layers, so the same packet will show up as going through multiple Windows components (unlike Npcap, which only gets them at one place).

Pktmon's ETL capture files can also be [converted to .pcapng](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/pktmon/pktmon-pcapng-support) for use in Wireshark.

> Alternatively I would go for a third party tool if there is no other solution, preferably something simpler / more light weight then Wireshark

Wireshark comes with two command-line tools: `tshark` which captures packets to a terminal (very much like tcpdump, only with Wireshark's dissecting capabilities) and `dumpcap` which outputs the raw pcapng file (like tcpdump with the `-w` option).

(Other tools may also directly use the same Npcap driver that gets installed alongside Wireshark, e.g. quite possibly there's a tcpdump port for it; though you'd need to pay attention to Npcap's licensing which has a special exception for Wireshark. Some of those tools may also need Npcap to be installed in "WinPcap-compatible" mode.)

Comment: pktmon sounds promising, I'll give it a try. Normally I'm using Wireshark to do it, but since Npcap usually requires installations (or at least I couldn't get it to work with the portable version), I'm looking for a simpler solution. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, with raw sockets the application can create it's own TCP/UDP header, and with a regular socket this is left to the socket itself?! So in conclusion netstat only monitors the "regular sockets" created by the OS, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, entries in netstat are just "regular sockets".

Comment: I think the command line parameter is not correct in you example, should't it be `-t` instead of `-p` ?? Or the whole command: `pktmon filter add -t ICMP`

Comment: Probably should be `-t`, yes.

Answer (score 2):

A free tool that can detect ICMP probes is
[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Once you choose the network adapter and start capturing,
you may set the Display filter to ICMP.

Here is an example for detecting `ping localhost`:

[image]

Comment: thanks but as I stated in my question, I'm already using wireshark.

Comment: @Albin your questions doesn't mention that you are using Wireshark, it does mention that you would like to use something more light weight.